# Inserting UIImageView as subview lag

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView that contains a pretty big image (3 +/- MB) and I am inserting it to be used as a background image as a subview like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
}
```

The problem is when the view is pushed by the navigation controller, the transition isn't smooth; it's very choppy because (I assume) the image is large and loading it into the image view is expensive. I used to use

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"foobar"]];
```

but because the image is so large, that code magnified the picture and it only shows a very small part of it, and very close up.

Is there a better/more efficient way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me in the end was to create a UIImageView in MainWindow.xib and set it to the image, that way it doesn't have to be loaded and unloaded every time the view changes, and gives the flow of the app some continuity. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What I'd try is this: resize the image first, to be the size it will actually be in the interface. To do so, redraw the image into an image context (`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`) using its `drawInRect:` method. Lots of info on this in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html

For example, to scale an image down to half its size:

```
UIImage* lin = [UIImage imageNamed: @"lin.png"];
CGSize s = lin.size;
CGFloat scale = 0.5;
s.width *= scale; s.height *= scale;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(s, YES, 0);
[lin drawInRect:(CGRect){{0,0}, s}];
lin = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Also, the source of the inefficiency might lie elsewhere. Use the new Debug menu in the simulator to look for other stuff being drawn inefficiently in your interface. There's a good WWDC 2011 video on drawing efficiently. Animations are exactly where these inefficiencies manifest themselves, so I think you're on the right track.

Comment: I know the imageView is the problem because commenting out the `[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0]` line removes the lag.

Comment: The image, maybe - not the imageView. UIImageView is a very efficient way to draw an image; there's no need for some other way, this is exactly what UIImageView is for.

Comment: I'm reading the section of the chapter of your book about graphics contexts, but I'm pretty lost. How do I use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to scale the image?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this "but because the image is so large, that code magnified the picture and it only shows a very small part of it, and very close up.", you can set the frame of your UIImageView with the setFrame method like this:

```
[yourImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,xWidth, yHeight)];
```

If yourImageView is on top of the viewcontroller's view, you can do this:

```
[yourViewController.yourImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,yourViewController.view.frame.size.width, yourViewController.view.frame.size.height)];
```